# Issues with admin part

Tags: django, django-admin

I am developing an app which **extends** the **auth_user** table, whenever any user register to the app, its one instance is created in the extended table,It works very well from simple  url(manually), but when I login from admin side and add user it will also create the instance in extended table but does not show or take the user name, it just shows the blank row.

model.py code is as:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
class Drinker(models.Model):
       user     =models.OneToOneField(User)
       birthday =models.DateField()
       name     =models.CharField(max_length=100)

       def __unicode__(self):
             return self.name

#create our user object to attach to our drinker object

def create_drinker_user_callback(sender, instance, **kwargs):
      drinker, new=Drinker.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_drinker_user_callback, User)
```

the last 3 lines three create the instance in extended table drinker but does not shows any value just take the user_id from auth_user table. it does not take name and birthday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not populating the Drinker.name field.
The row is blank because the **unicode**() method is returning nothing.

One way to solve this would be to set it explicitly in the signal handler:

```
def create_drinker_user_callback(sender, instance, **kwargs):
      drinker, new=Drinker.objects.get_or_create(user=instance, name=instance.get_full_name())
post_save.connect(create_drinker_user_callback, User)
```

or ditch the (possibly redundant) name field altogether and normalise it a bit:

```
class Drinker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

Comment: the 2nd option does not work and 1st option gives an error of global name 'user' is not defined

Comment: I've edited the first answer - user.get... should have been instance.get... but if you want me to correct the second one you'll have to say more than "doesn't work"

Comment: ok, perhaps you need to be more specific about the error. Where is "the blank row"? Does the User object have a name set at all, since that's what's being displayed?

Comment: extended table has three columns user_id(foregin key , id from auth table),name and birthday.
it only takes the user_id from auth table and the rest of the fields are empty and when i tried to create that instance of same user from admin side then it tells me that the instance of same user already exist.but there is no instance with that user name there is just a blank row

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the 2nd option does not work"?

Comment: class Drinker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16593/discussion-between-neeraj-and-moopet)